# Passing NSManagedObject from one view controller to another

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a uitableview which is filled with core data objects. I need to pass object for selected row to detail view controller. Following is my code for it:
**Alert Screen:**

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowAlertDetails" {
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? AlertDetailsViewController {
            if let blogIndex = tblvwAlerts!.indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row {
                let objAlert:Alert = arrReferrals[blogIndex] as! Alert
                destination.objAlert = objAlert
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Detail View Controller:

```
class AlertDetailsViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var tblvwHitDetail: UITableView?
var objAlert:Alert = Alert()
```

I am getting following error when I am trying to copy object from first page to detail page:

```
CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Alert'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by calling Alert() method in var objAlert:Alert = Alert(). You can set Alert as an Implicitly unwrapped value var objAlert:Alert!. It will be initially nil and then it will hold the reference of the managed objected which is passed from the previous controller.